# How can I accelerate the matrix multiplication XAX^T when A is sparse?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose `X` has `r` rows and `c` columns, so that `A` is a `c` by `c` matrix. If the total count of non-zero elements in `A` (call it `z`) is small then the following Python/pseudocode is plenty fast enough. If `c` is large though, and if `z` is bigger than `c`, then I don't have any reasonable ideas for how to accelerate the 3-way product, even approximately.

```
from itertools import product

def naive_threeway_matmul(X, A):
  """
    X: (r,c) dense nested arrays
    A: (c,c) sparse matrix, stored as {(i,j): value}
   
    rtn: (r,r) dense nested arrays: X @ A @ X.transpose()
  """
  r = len(X)
  c = len(A)
  rtn = [[0]*r for _ in range(r)]
  for (u,v) in product(range(r), repeat=2):
    rtn[u][v] = sum(
      X[u][i] * value * X[v][j]
      for (i,j), value in A.items()
    )
  return rtn
```

So we have a reasonable `O(r^2 z)` solution, and by computing a sparse-dense product followed by a dense-dense product we can get an `O(r^2 c)` solution (if `z ~ c`), but both of those are still effectively some cubic function. Is there an algorithm to bring the runtime down closer to `O(r^2)` when `c` is large and `z ~ c`, even approximately?

I don't really care about numpy or jax or other accelerators right now; I can optimize the code later.

Comment: Is `A` symmetric?

Comment: No. Everything above the main diagonal is zero, and on average each row has a small, constant number of elements, but there is no additional structure.